# C# List<string> to JavaScript String Conversion

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a C# `List<String>`, and I need to convert it to a `JavaScript` list of strings.

I'm currently stuck at:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer =
        new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
test = oSerializer.Serialize(tempString);
```

In `JavaScript`, I can get it like this (test is a protected string variable)

```
var servervalue = '<%=test %>';
```

In the console I get

```
var servervalue = '["100000001","200000002","200000003","300000006","300000007"]';
```

and I need to get it without the single quotation marks, like this:

```
["100000001", "200000002", "200000003", "300000006",
                                       "300000007"];
```

Comment: You should use `Newtsonsoft.Json`, Microsoft actually recommends it over the built in serializer.  Also, you could simply use a global or Session and assign the value, depending on your implementation.  Not sure your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the list to be wrapped by `'` quotes, you can easily fix this by removing the quotes that appear around the `<%=test %>` in the code.

```
var servervalue = <%=test%>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var servervalue = eval('<%=test %>');
```

You also can use `eval` to change the string to Array